# Something went wrong while saving the new password Magento 2

Tags: magento2, password, password-recovery, change-password

When I update my password with the "Reset my password" page, it shows me this error: "Something went wrong while saving the new password.". 
Please check the screenshot. 
I have tried to NULL the `rp_token` value, but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue, check this report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18256

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141183)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141183)

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue in Magento 2.2.6 (check [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18256))

This [patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bc8d3d5d0ead9779cb22d19201cd731719a79b0c) fixes it.

In `app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php`, in function `resetPassword`:

**BEFORE**

```
    $this->sessionManager->destroy();
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

**AFTER**

```
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->sessionManager->destroy();
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

Comment: greate solution thank you @Amanud working for me...

Answer (score 0):

First login to your server with SSH, then go to the folder root of site.
Next, create a new admin user by using the command below:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="demo" --admin-password="demo123" --admin-email="demo@gmail.com" --admin-firstname="Lof of" --admin-lastname="Coder"
```

Login to admin panel using the new account, then change the password of account that you lost

Comment: I am talking about the front end side.So why is should create the new admin?Do you think is it related to my issue?

Comment: you haven't mention that this is for frontend, i thought you are  trying to reset your admin side password

Comment: So do you have the solution for the front end side?