# Customer Reset Password not working in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, forgot-password

I am trying to reset my password as a customer. After going to the link received from email when i try to reset my password i am getting this error. See https://prnt.sc/p7ksmr.

Can any one help me in this.

```
namespace Smartwave\Porto\Model;


class AccountManagement extends \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement
{

private function matchCustomerByRpToken(string $rpToken):CustomerInterface
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
        'rp_token',
        $rpToken
    );
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize(1);
    $found = $this->customerRepository->getList(
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
    );
    if ($found->getTotalCount() > 1) {
        //Failed to generated unique RP token
        throw new ExpiredException(
            new Phrase('Reset password token expired.')
        );
    }
    if ($found->getTotalCount() === 0) {
        //Customer with such token not found.
        throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField(
            'rp_token',
            $rpToken
        );
    }
    //Unique customer found.
    return $found->getItems()[0];
}

public function resetPassword($email, $resetToken, $newPassword)
{
    if (!$email) {
        $customer = $this->matchCustomerByRpToken($resetToken);
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
    } else {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($email);
    }
    //Validate Token and new password strength
    $this->validateResetPasswordToken($customer->getId(), $resetToken);
    $this->credentialsValidator->checkPasswordDifferentFromEmail(
        $email,
        $newPassword
    );
    $this->checkPasswordStrength($newPassword);
    //Update secure data
    $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
    $customerSecure->setRpToken(null);
    $customerSecure->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
    $customerSecure->setPasswordHash($this->createPasswordHash($newPassword));
    /*$this->sessionManager->destroy();
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer); */
$this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
$this->sessionManager->destroy();
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Your Magento version please?

Comment: @Sumit My magento version is 2.3

Comment: Any error log you've in the logs file regarding the issue?

Comment: @Sumit. I tried the solution given by Rk Rathod. It worked when i changed directly my core file. But after overriding the model, its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php` in your theme.

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite\AccountManagement" />
</config>
```

We need to copy the full `AccountManagement.php` file as it contains private functions and variables and do the required changes in `resetPassword()`.

Create AccountManagement.php file under `Vendor\Module\Model\Rewrite` with your code.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Getting this error https://prnt.sc/p7nmh8 when i run setup de:compile command

Comment: Permission issue, please remove the generated folder content and give permission 777 to the generated folder.

Comment: Removed generated folder and given 777 prmission....still same issue

Comment: Plz help what to do?

Comment: Please wait, I'm looking into it on my installation.

Comment: Than you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98806/discussion-between-nafisa-and-sumit).

Answer (score 0):

Refernce [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259752/72911)

This is an issue in Magento 2.2.6 (check [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18256))

This [patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bc8d3d5d0ead9779cb22d19201cd731719a79b0c) fixes it.

In `app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement.php`, in function `resetPassword`:

**BEFORE**

```
    $this->sessionManager->destroy();
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

**AFTER**

```
    $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
    $this->sessionManager->destroy();
    $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**And Also Give Permission**

Comment: This worked from when i changed from core. After overriding the file its not working

Comment: please attach code of overriding file

Comment: I Updated my ans

Comment: define in di.xml ??

Comment: YEs......... <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" type="Smartwave\Porto\Model\AccountManagement" />

Comment: remove `atchCustomerByRpToken` function and also define in module file this code `<sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>`

Comment: and after this use this command `rm -rf generated/*` and `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: need to add it else getting this error https://prnt.sc/p7m354

Comment: Still getting issue

Comment: yes becuse of `atchCustomerByRpToken` function is private so just remove that function in your file and try adn also post that code in question,

Comment: If i remove that i am geting this error https://prnt.sc/p7m354

Comment: after this changes please follow this step im added in my answer

Comment: Ran all the commands, still not working

Comment: still getting same error ?

Comment: Yes getting this erro  https://prnt.sc/p7ksmr. after overriding files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98804/discussion-between-nafisa-and-rk-rathod).